# How do I set rapidFailProtectionInterval in IIS using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

I'm trying to configure the Application Pool of WsusPool, on a MS WSUS setup, to raise the Failure Rapid-Fail Protection Interval from 5 minutes to 30 minutes as an administrator using PowerShell.

I'm able to get the setting using

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Console

Import-Module WebAdministration

$WsusPool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\WsusPool\
$WsusPool.failure.rapidFailProtectionInterval

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 5
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 3000000000
TotalDays         : 0.00347222222222222
TotalHours        : 0.0833333333333333
TotalMinutes      : 5
TotalSeconds      : 300
TotalMilliseconds : 300000
```

But I get an error when I try save a change to the value

```
$WsusPool.failure.rapidFailProtectionInterval = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30
$WsusPool | Set-Item

Set-Item : Specified cast is not valid.
At line:1 char:13
+ $WsusPool | Set-Item
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Item], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : path,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

Some data of the system:

```
Version of PowerShell:

PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  1490

Operating system:

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption, Version, ServicePackMajorVersion, OSArchitecture, WindowsDirectory


Caption                 : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
Version                 : 10.0.17763
ServicePackMajorVersion : 0
OSArchitecture          : 64-bit
WindowsDirectory        : C:\Windows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` like this

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty '//*[@name="WsusPool"]//failure' -Name rapidFailProtectionInterval -Value (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30)
```

[Here](https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/iis-powershell-user-guide-comparing-representative-iis-ui-tasks) is a very helpful page on the subject

Comment: Thx alot. That did the trick :)
I actually tried using Set-WebConfigurationProperty first, but couldn't figure out the proper IIS syntax for accessing the properties :/

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting this as the answer by clicking the check mark. You can always change it later if someone offers a better answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit new to asking questions in stackowerflow so I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered but I had to dig deep in further and found this link where Michael Felkin has put together extensive property settings for IIS which I found marvelous.  Kudo to him for doing that...

[You can find all that info here](https://powershell.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/iAPPWebRole.txt)

Here is the shorter version of that I used:

```
$appPool = New-Item "IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPools" -Force
$appPool.failure.rapidFailProtection = "False"
$appPool | set-item
```

Keep in mind that the **last line is crucial** here in order to set the changes.

Hope, someone will find it helpful! :)

Comment: link broken :'(